# Powershell - Variables Array's - Finding Folders then Files in Folder

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell

I really need some help with Powershell, complete novice in Powershell

I have the command below, which outputs a list of paths searching for folder called "xyz" created multiple times on a share, used as a variable

```
$FOLDERLISTS = (Get-ChildItem \\server\share -Recurse | Where-Object { ( $._PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ($_.Name -like "xyz" -and ( $_.mode -match "d") | % { Write-Host $_.FullName })
```

How can I use the multiple folder paths, can I set this as a variable?

Basically I just want to get the folder paths, then run another Get-ChildItem against each folder path the above command outputs, so if it was a single variable the command would looks like;

```
Get-ChildItem "@ABOVECOMMAND" -Recurse | Where-Object ( !($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.lenght -le 1000000 )
```

Can I somehow use ForEach for this to run over the multiple paths?

```
foreach ($FOLDERLIST in $FOLDERLISTS)
{
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.lenght -le 1000000 }
}
```

Or

```
$FOLDERLISTS | ForEach-Object{
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.lenght -le 1000000 }
```

Or just export the paths to a text file and import into the command? Completely stuck.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Don't see why either of your last two suggestions shouldn't work

Comment: Neither of the last two ideas would ctually work as written. Neither has a variable to reference the current iteration of the loop. In the first idea it would be $FOLDERLIST. In the second idea it would be $_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try should be more like this:

```
foreach ($FOLDERLIST in $FOLDERLISTS)
{
Get-ChildItem $FOLDERLIST -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.lenght -le 1000000 }
}
```

OR your second try like this:

```
$FOLDERLISTS | ForEach-Object{
Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) -and $_.lenght -le 1000000 }
```

Comment: Thanks campbell I think from your comment I can see where I was going wrong, get-childitem was not passed anything!! I'll give this a try looks like a winner!